# How to Stop Handler thread?

Tags: android, android-handlerthread

I want to stop this thread on button click.

```
TIME_OUT = 45000;
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
         Intent i = new 
         Intent(MapsActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
         startActivity(i);
         finish();
       }
     }, TIME_OUT);
```

I am using above handler in `onCreate` of an Activity. I want to stop it. How to stop this thread on click of any button or on click of on Back Pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent i = new
                Intent(MapsActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
};
handler.post(runnable);

// use this when you don't want callback to be called anymore
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Comment: where to use handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)

Comment: @AnkeshRoy when you not need callback to be called. For example, when you start handler thread and user already end the activity and you dont want handler’s callback to run, so you removeCallbacks() in onDestroy().

Comment: app is getting crashed when apply on onDestroy();

Comment: what is the error log?

Comment: handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); indicating error at this line with Cannot instantiate the type Runnable when i am removing it working well but my app is not getting closed .

Comment: please check that your runnable is not null first, make sure it is initialized before you call that statement.

Answer (score 6):

```
Handler handler = new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new 
                     Intent(MapsActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }, TIME_OUT);
```

Then you can use [Handler#removeCallbacksAndMessages](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacksAndMessages(java.lang.Object)) to remove this or any callback.

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

Comment: where to use handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); onStop() or onPause() or onBackPressed()

Comment: you can remove it just before your `finish();` call

Answer (score 3):

Okay the best option is to use a boolean as a flag like that

```
TIME_OUT = 45000;

//add this boolean
boolean run =true;

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //run this method only when run is true
                 if(run==true){

                    //your code
                   }

            }
        }, TIME_OUT);

             //on button click just change the boolean to flag and it will stop the run method
              //on click
              run=false;
```

Comment: where to use this comple mthod on activity please explain i am new in android.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
Handler handler;
Button b;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       

handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new
                    Intent(MapsActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
           finish();
        }
    };
    handler.post(runnable);

button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View arg0) {  
               handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);  
            }  
        });  

   
}


 
}
```

Comment: please try to explain your answer.

Comment: while using handler on onCreate() method so i want to know where to stop it.

Comment: On button click linstener we stop handler here.

Comment: this should be like this     handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);